# Change of Basis and Coordinate system question

Tags: matrices, rotations

My apologies in advance: I am not very proficient in the field of mathematics.  If my question seems discombobulated, it probably is, and I would *greatly* appreciate your help cleaning it up!  Alright, onward...

I have a few coordinate systems to coordinate. I'm using a camera that detects markers in space and returns their location and attitude (in a vector and rotation matrix).  I'm using a machine that moves in a room along standard Cartesian axes that are pre-determined in the room.  The camera has its own coordinate system according to which it is detecting the markers.

I have a matrix, $R$ that can take a vector with respect to the room coordinate system and rotate it so that it is now expressed relative to the camera coordinate system.

I take record the position of the markers on the machine at an instant ($T_o$), and would like to report how much the machine has rotated ($D$) with respect to the room's coordinate system given the instantaneous positions of the markers ($T_i$).

$D=T_i^{-1}T_o$

yields the rotation in the camera's coordinate system.

$D=R^{-1}T_i^{-1}T_oR$

seems to give the correct answer, but I don't understand it.

Please let me know the formula for $D$ or, if the formula above is correct, could you give a quick explanation for it?

Comment: Please don't yell (all capitals is the on-line equivalent of yelling). In this site, we can use italics and boldface for emphasis, so you can type `*greatly*` or `_greatly_` to produce "*greatly*"; and `**greatly**` to get **greatly**.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I have modified my question.